# cv::split or Eigen::Stride: Which is more efficient for mapping multi-channel matrices from OpenCV to Eigen structures

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen

I am mapping a multi-channel OpenCV [`cv::Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html) to a [`Eigen::Matrix`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html). There are a couple ways I thought of to do it. Ignoring row- vs column-major for the sake of the example, the first is:

```
Map<Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>, Stride<3,1>> R((double*)mat_cv.data);
Map<Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>, Stride<3,1>> G((double*)mat_cv.data + 1);
Map<Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>, Stride<3,1>> B((double*)mat_cv.data + 2);
```

The second is to split the channels in OpenCV first and then map each individual `cv::Mat`:

```
cv::Mat cv_mat;
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
cv::split(cv_mat, channels);
MatrixXd R = Map<Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>>((double*)channels[0].data, 10, 10);
MatrixXd G = Map<Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>>((double*)channels[1].data, 10, 10);
MatrixXd B = Map<Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>>((double*)channels[2].data, 10, 10);
```

Which is the more efficient approach?

Or, is there something altogether different that I haven't considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach is, as you pointed out, a mapping of the matrices. Your second example is a mapping of **copies** of the `cv` matrix (the `split` function [copies](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=split#split)). Therefore, the first approach will be more efficient.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure how the split function worked. Great, thanks!